# <br> not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am loading data via Socket.io and, then wrap it in some HTML, then parse it with a DOMParser, add it to my container but `<br>` just get ignored.

This is the container:

[image: Container]

While this is the source code

```
<div webm-query="Lina.httpd.Access" webm-display="<span>%v</span><br />">
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
<span>212.142.132.240: GET / HTTP/1.1 -> 200</span><br></br>
</div>
```

Generated via

```
var data = ((Properties.Modifier && webm.Modifier[Properties.Modifier]) ?
                webm.Modifier[Properties.Modifier](Data) : Data);
var html = (Properties.Display) ? "<div>"+replaceAll("'", "\"", replaceAll("%k", Query, replaceAll("%v",data, roperties.Display)))+"</div>" :data;
return htmlString = (Properties.Display) ? new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml") : data;
```

Comment: works fine for me (FIDDLE)[http://jsfiddle.net/4KDMw/]

Comment: @Rhea yea I know but it's probably because I add them with `container.appendChild`

Comment: @BeryJu: Well, maybe if you showed how you're *actually* generating the output (e.g., the `appendChild` call), people would be able to help you. You said "Here is the source code" which very clearly means "I'm using this markup directly." Apparently you aren't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry, edited it in.

Comment: @BeryJu: And when you put code in questions (or answers), *mark it up correctly*. (I've fixed it for you this time, but c'mon, this isn't your first or second question.) There's the handy toolbar for that, and the **How to Format** callout to the right while you're writing/editing. You're really not helping yourself here. Quality questions, taking the time to present things clearly, attract quality answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<br>` tag is self-closing I believe, so you should not do `<br></br>` but should do `<br />`.

Comment: It is, but `<br>` works and also `document.createElement("br");` also output `<br>`. And I tried `<p>` instead of `<span>` and that had the same issue.

Comment: @BeryJu: According to the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.2.1), the end tag for `br` elements is even forbidden: *"Start tag: required, End tag: forbidden"*. Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: it infact was the Problem, I solved it with this
`if (Child.localName === "br") {
         Node.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        } else {
         Node.appendChild(Child);
}`

Comment: @BeryJu Nice to see your problem was fixed.

Comment: @BeryJu - The reason you were having problems is that you are parsing the built string as XML. That means that your br elements (and also the spans and div) are in the null namespace not the html namespace, so they were being treated as unknown elements rather than line break elements. Had you parsed the string as HTML, you wouldn't have had the problem.